# Vivado regular expression to match a net

Tags: regex, constraints, vivado

I need to set a false path on a 31 bit register.

Its name is `tttx_clk200Mhz_s2_reg[0]`, where '0' can be any number from 0 to 31.

I have tried the following

```
get_nets -hierarchical -regexp -filter { NAME =~  ".*tttx_clk200_s2_reg[\d+]/C.*" }
get_nets -hierarchical -regexp -filter { NAME =~  ".*tttx_clk200_s2_reg\[\d+\]/C.*" }
get_nets -hierarchical -regexp -filter { NAME =~  ".*tttx_clk200_s2_reg\\[\d+\\]/C.*" }
```

but none of them work.

Basically below is the command for one signal of the register which works

```
set_false_path -from [get_pins -hierarchical -filter { NAME =~  "*tttx_clk200_s2_reg[1]/C*" }] -to [get_pins -hierarchical *pll_off_en_reg/D*]
```

now I want to repeat that for remaining 31 siganls

Comment: It seems you are missing the `Mhz` part in your pattern. There is also no `/C` in your example string. Perhaps try a pattern like `.*tttx_clk200Mhz_s2_reg\[(?:\d|[12][0-9]|3[01])].*` https://regex101.com/r/yl9nT6/1

Comment: Does `NAME =~ "tttx_clk200(Mhz)?_s2_reg\[[0-9]+]"` work?

Comment: Sorry I made a typo in my original post. The signal name is tttx_clk200_s2_reg

Comment: The following has worked for me
{ NAME =~  ".*tttx_clk200_s2_reg\[\d+\].C.*" } I don't know why I couldn't escape the / before C. So I just replaced it with '.' (any character). But I wonder what is the correct syntax

Comment: It does not look like you must escape `/` here. `get_nets -hierarchical -regexp -filter { NAME =~  ".*tttx_clk200_s2_reg\[\d+]/C.*" }` should work.